# C++: Accessing the values of an "array pointer" without the dereferencing operator?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dereference

Apologies if this question was already asked, but there are too many questions with C++ arrays and pointers as that I could go through all of them..

Let's say we declare a double array like this:

```
double val[3] = {-3.1415, 6.2430, +37};

// Declare and initialize pointer variable: 
double * pointer = &val[0]; 
cout << "Elements of the array are: " << endl; 
cout << pointer[0] << " " << pointer[1] << " " << pointer[2] << endl;
```

What confused me is how I get as output the correct values stored in the double array `val`, without having to use *dereferencing operator* *, so for example `*pointer[0]`..

Comment: `operator[]()` is just a memory offset operation. That's how it works for regular arrays, and that's how it works on a pointer.

Comment: `a[b]` is by definition the same as `*(a + b)`, so there is your `*`.

Comment: Did you want this: [https://ideone.com/6iuoAf](https://ideone.com/6iuoAf)  ? I am confused at what question are you asking.

Comment: for c-style arrays like `MyArray[Index]`, that is equivalent to `*(MyArray + Index)`, so you ARE dereferencing using the (built-in) * operator

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt May I ask: Why is it that pointer[1] means `*(pointer + 1)`? Is this the way it is coded? Thank you.

Comment: That rule follows from the definition of the language, i.e. the ISO C++ standard. BTW: Important reading for understanding this would be on the topic of "pointer arithmetic in C++".

Answer (score 2):

`pointer` points at the first double in an array of packed doubles.

`pointer[1]` means `*(pointer+1)` in a ridiculously fundamental way, so  much so that `1[pointer]` works.  (don't do that btw)

If you have an array of data, then adding 1 to a pointer to the first element gets a pointer to the second.

Comment: May I ask: Why is it that `pointer[1]` means `*(pointer + 1)`? Is this the way it is coded? Thank you.

Comment: Also: How can I understand the expression `*(pointer + 1)`? I would rewrite this as `*pointer + *1 = val[0] + *1`, but what is `*1`?

Comment: Your rewriting is not valid. Arithmetic (adding/substracting) on pointers follows special rules, it operates in multiples of the type of the pointer. So, `pointer + 1` will give you the address of the next object. Even though C++ uses `*` for multiplication as well doesn't mean you can apply rules valid for multiplication when it means dereference.